# How to convert the svg file to mxgraph's xml?

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, mxgraph

I have many **SVG** files that drawed by other tools.And now,I want to edit those file by mxGraph and save it use mxGraph's XML.Anybody konws how to convert the SVG files to mxGraph XML?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [project](https://github.com/jgraph/svg2xml) if you want them as stencil XML format.

You can use SVGs as shapes the same way any image type can be used, though.

Comment: Thank you for that! But I tried it and the result is that can't be used.The svg file will be transed to what is different from the svg.